# apache : disable mod_deflate - [error] an unknown filter

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora, mod-deflate, mod-pagespeed

I am running apache with mod_pagespeed on fedora (14), and I am getting the error message:

```
[error] an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE
```

a lot. I know this is because mod_deflate is not loaded, but that's good, I don't want to load it (the load balancer takes care of gzipping etc, and we get unexpected results when deflate is on the webservers too)

However I can't figure out where it is being referenced, I have used this command to look through all files in /etc/httpd

```
 find . -type f -exec grep -li "deflate" {} \;
```

**update** that command also searches through the conf.d subdir - and I used a similar thing to look through all the .htaccess files on the server

```
 find . -type f -name ".htaccess" -exec grep -li "deflate" {} \;
```

and the only references are in .conf files and they are commented out with `#` (apache has been restarted) **update** for example

```
# LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
```

How can I find where it is being referenced and remove it?

**update** I have tried to run `a2enmod` and `a2dismod`, but there are not such commands. `yum install a2dismod` does not find anything to install. The names of those commands and the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory I have only come across with ubuntu, I don't know the equivalent fedora / fedora-installed-via-yum commands

the installed modules list, (but since the error is that the filter is unknown, I am not sure what I am looking for? If mod_deflate was in this list then surely I wouldn't get the error?)

```
Loaded Modules:
core_module (static)
mpm_prefork_module (static)
http_module (static)
so_module (static)
auth_basic_module (shared)
auth_digest_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
authn_alias_module (shared)
authn_anon_module (shared)
authn_dbm_module (shared)
authn_default_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
authz_owner_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_dbm_module (shared)
authz_default_module (shared)
ldap_module (shared)
authnz_ldap_module (shared)
include_module (shared)
log_config_module (shared)
logio_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
ext_filter_module (shared)
mime_magic_module (shared)
expires_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
usertrack_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
dav_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
info_module (shared)
dav_fs_module (shared)
vhost_alias_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
actions_module (shared)
speling_module (shared)
userdir_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
substitute_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
cache_module (shared)
suexec_module (shared)
disk_cache_module (shared)
cgi_module (shared)
version_module (shared)
cband_module (shared)
dnssd_module (shared)
pagespeed_module (shared)
perl_module (shared)
php5_module (shared)
python_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message you get actually means your current apache configuration needs `mod-deflate` to be loaded.  Your apache wants to use `mod-deflate` as a processing filter, either an outgoing filter or an incoming filter.

See the [apache documentation about filters](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/filter.html).

As you don't want to use `mod-deflate` you have disabled it and the output of `DUMP_MODULES` doesn't show it.  You now need to look for filter instructions that make use of `mod-deflate` and de-activate them.  Looking for the keyword `DEFLATE` is a good start but also look for `INFLATE` (`mod-deflate` is also used to decompress incoming response body).  And, if you don't find anything, even looking for `Filter` may help (but then you'll probably get a longer list of matches).  Try out commands like:

```
grep -r Filter /etc/apache2/*
find /var/www -type f -name .htaccess -exec grep Filter {} \;
```

You might also need to look for other included files as some packages (some web applications like phpmyadmin and others) usually install apache configuration directives under different directories (at least this is the case with some Debian/Ubuntu packages, not sure with Fedora).

You could also completely deactivate the filter module (`mod-filter`) and the mime module (`mod-mime`, which defines the Add/RemoveFilter directives) but that will de-activate other functionalities you probably need.

Comment: +1 for your effort, but I can't find any more references to deflate, daren't deactivate other modules on a live server can can't recreate on my dev box :(

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Fedora are you using?

You not only need to look for the `deflate` word but also need to look for `include` statements in your apache configuration files.  Most linux distros automatically include all files from a directory such as `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` into their apache configuration.  It might be your case.

Your distribution probably includes the `a2enmod` and `a2dismod` apache utilities that helps to manage apache modules.  Those utilities usually only manage links in the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directories which are then included as I said above.  Try to use these commands to manage the list of modules your apache is using.

Comment: ´a2dismod deflate´ should disable it globally. one can simply delete the module's .ini file as well. guess requires reading logs, to find out what exactly tries to deflate the output.

Comment: ... ´apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES´ might give a clue.

Comment: thanks for the responses, I have edited my question with more detail

Comment: @CodeMonkey Thanks for the update, I now understand the issue differently and have provided you a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check htaccess files for something like

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
```